# why POSTGRES database uses postgres user as superuser/default user ? how to change it?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13, superuser

we are planning to install postgresql-13 on our production cluster. but as we have postgres as default user , i want to remove it and use superuser of prod cluster. can any on suggest how to install psql-13 with prod superuser as a default user ?

prod superuser should own all file and folder which will be generated while installing.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can define the name of the superuser when running [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-initdb.html). But what do you mean with "superuser of prod cluster"?

Comment: Use -U username or --username=username when running initdb

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the bootstrap user name when you create the cluster:

```bash
initdb -U fuzzy -E UTF8 --locale=en_US.utf8 /path/to/data/directory
```

But you can also rename the user any time later:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# CREATE ROLE x LOGIN SUPERUSER;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# \connect - x
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "x".
postgres=# ALTER ROLE postgres RENAME TO fuzzy;
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# \connect - fuzzy
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "fuzzy".
postgres=# DROP ROLE x;
DROP ROLE
postgres=# \quit
```